# Example of inbox items?

Tags: support, status-completed, api-v2, inbox

Would it be possible to get an example of each type returned by the inbox, Eg careers messages, and whatever meta questions are.

Do careers invites/chat messages/etc have ids? And what is their site?

Comment: I'm marking this as [status-completed] since examples for each type are provided [in the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item) now.

Comment: @george thanks :) but the examples use example.stackexchange.com even for careers items, that doesn't look like right?

Comment: @Jonathan. - careers items are attached to stackoverflow.com, which maps correctly for examples cases.  There isn't a "careers site" on the event.  I'll add a note to that effect in the next deploy, since it's a bit confusing still.

Comment: @KevinMontrose, so the icon will a careers icon? Or will I have to check show one manually?

Comment: @Jonathan. - it will be a Stack Overflow icon.